# W/webcore(2733): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I have three web Views next to one another, for display of seperate spinners.  I get this error somtimes, which causes problems in window rendering.

heres my xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
   <LinearLayout 

    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/measure_view" 
            android:background="#77000000"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:focusable="true"/>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/input_view" 
            android:background="#77000000"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:focusable="true"/>
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/output_view" 
            android:background="#77000000"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:focusable="true"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks,  Nathaniel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who has this problem:

From what I've found there's some threading going on when the webviews are created, and certain variables - width for example, are being referenced across threads.  This is to quote the code "imperfect" because sometimes the data is unavailable at rendering time.

Look at this:

[CODE](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/webkit/WebViewCore.java.htm)

and ctrl-f the text of the error "Can't get viewWidth"... and you'll see what I'm talking about.

An interesting continuation here is that i was using multiple webviews - this may have compounded that problem.  Another interesting aspect is that the webview which failed in my code was always the first one to have contents loaded into it, although it did not always fail.

My solution has been to let things fail the first time, and then re-render the failed web-view.

Hope this helps.

Nathaniel.

Comment: Could you share how you detect the failure, and how you re-rendered the webview?

Comment: Hey Steelight, np.  Basically I just assume the failure on all three views and re-draw them all.  In terms of how I handle the re-render its: web_view.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload(true);");

I was using JavaScript a lot, so if you don't want to do that I'm not sure what the best way to re-render is.

Comment: doesnt reload(true) mean you are clearing the browser cache, so will need to redownload the whole webpage once again? quite inefficient, no? there must be a better solution for this....

Comment: Yea, it's pretty inefficient.  No disagreement there.  I didn't ever find away around it short of ditching web views all together.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when it doen't load? do you get an error in the logcat?

after loading the data, try doing this:

```
webView.refreshDrawableState();
```

Comment: No errors anywhere that I can find. I'll try that refresh though.  Thanks.

Comment: Hey, so i found this error 05-24 16:07:29.778: W/webcore(1639): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout  - happen to know anything about htat?  I'm starting to go nuts lol.