# WebView cant be created

Tags: android, layout, webview

Hey guys i got a little problem i want to create a WebView by code.
this is my code i wanna use.

```
WebView WVakten = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
                WVakten.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                WVakten.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                WVakten.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                WVakten.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                WVakten.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.CLOSE);
                WVakten.loadUrl("http://www.google.de");
                WVakten.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://")) {
                            view.getContext().startActivity(
                                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }}});
```

But when i try to start the app i only get the following error:

08-10 19:03:10.560: W/webcore(7134): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout

But i simply dont get why i am getting this error.

Comment: Maybe this can give you some answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743051/w-webcore2733-cant-get-the-viewwidth-after-the-first-layout

Comment: where do you create the View?

Comment: onCreate() - This is where you should do all of your normal static set up: create views, bind data to lists, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is to create a layout in a xml file and add the webview to the layout in the onCreate.

Example:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum ="1.0"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">    

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/article"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="0.90"
    class="nieuws.com.ArticleFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the on create of the ArticleFragment you simply add the following code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    m_webview = new WebView(getActivity());
    m_webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    m_webview.setWebViewClient(new jWebViewClient());
    return m_webview;
 }
```

Hope this helps

Jasper

Answer (score 0):

I think you are either not setting the content view or not adding your `WebV`enter code here`iew` to the main layout.
If the Webview has no surrounding layout, then at the end of your code in onCreate() add:

```
setContentView(WVakten);
```

In that case the LayoutParams are not necessary

If you have already set your content view to a layout, then you need to get a reference to that layout and add your view:

```
LinearLayout yourLayout = findViewById(R.id.something);
yourLayout.addView(WVakten);
```

In that case the LayoutParams will be necessary and must be of the type of the parent Layout. So if your `WebView` is surrounded with a LinearLayout you must use

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(...);
```